# Strong Name signing order for dependant projects

Tags: c#, .net

I have two project A(.EXE) and B(.DLL) in the solution. A references B. If I delay sign both and send them for full signing. Will A be able to load B after ? Or do I have to get B fully signed first, and then add a binary reference to that in Project A, delay sign A and send for full signing ?

Comment: Is strong name signing done at the project level? Is B a .dll?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4fa028b(v=vs.90).aspx